# Unison: don't treat root folder deletion as something that needs to sync?

Tags: sync, unison

I'm trying to get Unison to sync between two folders, but on one side, if I don't have the existing folder, it tries to delete the other side (the folder with everything in it). So if I have

```
/folderA/fileA
/folderA/fileB
/folderB/
```

If I delete `folderB`, and then run `unison -auto -batch -prefer newer folderA folderB`, it will try and delete `folderA` instead of creating `folderB` and copying the contents of `folderA` over to `folderB`.

Is this possible? It may sound like a weird request, but it's because I'm creating syncing scripts where new systems won't have `folderB` sometimes, and I don't want the computer to think that means `folderA` needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue. Unison is deleting `folderA` because you, after telling Unison that `folderA` and `folderB` should be synchronized, deleted `folderB`, so of course Unison wants to delete `folderA` to keep things syncronized. But you said the cases where `folderB` doesn't exist will be on **new systems** that, I presume, you haven't synced with `folderA` before (so there are no [archive files](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#archives) for this pair of roots). So when you run

```
unison -auto -batch -prefer newer folderA folderB
```

where `folderB` doesn't exist, Unison should happily create `folderB`.